# Sync SQLite Database to App Engine Datastore?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-app-engine

The android app stores the data in SQLite database during the offline mode. When online I want the app to sync (in both direction) with the datastore(database) in cloud server (App Engine). How do I implement this functionality, so that I can show the data captured on phone on a web application. Also please suggest any simple alternative way if any..

Comment: This is an overly broad question that doesn't really suit SO.  You are just going to get down modded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just write out my data as a String (using a format I can reconstruct my data with), pass that to AE, parse it and store/display it.

You could use json too.

or try http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.jp/2010/10/client-server-communication-with-json.html

for the sync part I use a timestamp.  If the timestamped result isn't recorded on the server, I record it.  I send back the recorded stamps to the client and delete them from the store.  Of course the server can also send back new results if a user's records were updated from a different client.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should implement some complex algorithm, that will be doing synchronization depending on your needs, and then make it in code on both side (server and client). This not quite a simple task, in general. Useful keywords for googling: SOAP, REST, JSON, ...